# Disabling tab space highlight in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I am setting up my new mac book for development. In vim (mac vim), with jellybeans color scheme, all the tab spaces are highlighted. This is annoying as left side of most of the instructions/line is in grey. I read about "TabLineFill", but not sure how to use it. Is there  a better way?
Thanks,
bsr

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague. What is it that you want to accomplish?

If you wish to change the color of the tabline,

```
hi TabLine guibg=Black guifg=White
```

If you wish to change the entire tabline to grey (like the left side),

```
hi TabLineFill guibg=#b0b8c0
```

If neither of this is what you wanted, you'll have to explain a bit more.

Comment: thank you for the help. Added an image which explains it better. I like to get rid of the dark highlight on the left side (tab/free space). Thanks again

Comment: @bsreekanth - Oh, I see. That is SpecialKey (or NonText) highlighting group. Take a look what is your background color with "hi Normal" and then do "hi SpecialKey guibg=...that background color...". It should go away.

Comment: @bsreekanth - The part that deals with line numbers is in the LineNr highlighting group (same procedure as above to change the background color).

Comment: thanks.. I didn't test it yet, but accept ur answer for pointing me to the right direction..

Answer (score 4):

It is too late to answer but today I also spend much time for searching its solution.
After trying many highlight group I found that it is `SpecialKey` that you need and me as well.

`hi SpecialKey ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE`

EDIT: you can find color value format with
`:h guibg`

Comment: +1 at least in the latest mac vim, it gives error "Cannot allocate color none"  I may have to play around it. may be it is cap sensitive.